# Is it possible to get reserved special numbers of double-precision binary floating-point with NumPy or some other package in Python

Tags: python, numpy, floating-point

per [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format), Double-precision binary floating-point has Exponents

> range from −1022 to +1023 because exponents of −1023 (all
>   0s) and +1024 (all 1s) are reserved for special numbers.

is it possible to get these special numbers with NumPy or other package in Python

Answer (score 0):

These special numbers are `Inf` and `NaN`:

`Infinity`

> Infinity is represented with an exponent of all 1s and a mantissa of all 0s. Depending on the sign bit, it can be a positive infinity(+∞) or negative infinity (-∞). The infinity is used in case of the saturation on maximum representable number so that the computation could continue.

`NaN`

> The value NaN (Not a Number) is used to represent a value that does not represent a real number. They are used in computations that generate undefined results so that with NaN the operations are defined for it to let the computations continue. NaN's are represented by a bit pattern with an exponent of all 1s and a non-zero mantissa. There are two categories of NaN: QNaN (Quiet NaN) and SNaN (Signalling NaN).

You can use them with `np.inf` and `np.nan`.